# Pygame check for collisions with the top most foreground rect

Tags: mouse, sprite, pygame, rect

I have 10 sprites which I objects of the main sprite I wrote with different images and starting positions etc. But they all behave the same way. They are sub sprites of the main sprite.

I want to be able to hold mouse click on one's rect and move it round the screen which works perfectly fine. But the problem is they all have the same controls click and drag to move them. So if I am clicking on one of the sprite rects and I drag it over another one it picks it up as well. And I don't want that to happen.

Is there a way to only check for collisions with the top most foreground rect or if someone could explain a way of doing this that would achieve similar results. I have had a look at the rect documentation but I can't find a solution.

```
def update(self,):
    self.move(self.rect)

def move(self,rect):

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and the_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        self.state = 1

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0, 0, 0) and the_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        self.state = 0

    if self.state == 0:
        the_rect.centerx = the_rect.centerx
        the_rect.centery =  the_rect.centery
    elif self.state == 1:
        (the_rect.centerx, the_rect.centery) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the pygame.mouse.get_pressed() function, use the [event queue](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) and check for a pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event. It will only get fired once when the button is first pressed.